# How to stop Cloudflare Workers from caching response?

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

Here's my worker:

```
var myArray = [
  "q2dl3fY.jpg",
  "rLNsDHr.jpg",
  "FsvOJHJ.jpg"
];

var socialPost = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  return event.respondWith(
    fetch("https://i.imgur.com/" + socialPost)
  )
})
```

All that I'm trying to do is pull a random image from Imgur.  The script is working correctly.

However, the results appear to be cached.  It's just showing the same image over and over instead of randomly rotating between the ones I have listed.

Comment: You never change `socialPost`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the results appear to be cached.

Not quite. This is occurring because you set `socialPost` only *once* throughout the entirety of your script. Instead, what you seem to want to do is pick a random array element every time the `fetch` event fires. To solve this, place the calculation of the `socialPost` variable *inside* the event listener callback:

```
var myArray = [
  "q2dl3fY.jpg",
  "rLNsDHr.jpg",
  "FsvOJHJ.jpg"
];

addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  var socialPost = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  return event.respondWith(
    fetch("https://i.imgur.com/" + socialPost)
  )
})
```